# Appending information to a tkinter label and removing whitespace

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

So, if I input a word "tkinter" then it'll give me the letter frequency. However, if I input "t k i n t e r " it'll give me totally different data. How do I remove the whitespace from any input, and then how do I append `key, value/float(len(user_input))*100, '%'` in a Tkinter Label?

I found how to replace whitespace, and with suggestions from helpful commentors, can successfully add text to a label that displays the data with the corresponding key. However, I have another question on how to remove the previous label each time you click the button?

code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from collections import Counter
import string


def let_freq():
    user_input = (e.get().lower()).translate(None, string.whitespace)
    res = ""
    value_alphabet = Counter(user_input)
    v = StringVar()

    label = Label(root, text="Result:", textvariable=v).grid(ipadx=5,ipady=5)

    for key, value in value_alphabet.items():
        print key, value/float(len(user_input))*100, '%'
        res += '\n'+key+'-'+`value/float(len(user_input))*100`+'%'

    v.set(res)

root = Tk()
e = Entry(root); assert isinstance(e, object); e.grid(ipadx=5, ipady=5)
button = Button(root, command=let_freq, width=16).grid(ipadx=5, ipady=5)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: have you tried searching python documentation, this site, or the internet for answers to these fundamental questions?

Comment: Yes, and nothing i've tried has worked otherwise I wouldn't have posted a question?

Comment: @komoka "it'll give me totally different data" is not enough -- what exactly will it give you?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.replace(" ","")` to remove the whitespace.

Below code might help to append result to tkinter label

```
from Tkinter import *
from collections import Counter


def let_freq():
    user_input = e.get().lower()
    user_input_Nowhitespaces = user_input.replace(" ", "")
    value_alphabet = Counter(user_input_Nowhitespaces)
    v = StringVar()
    label = Label(root,text="Result:",textvariable=v).grid(ipadx=5, ipady=5)
    res=""

    for key, value in value_alphabet.items():
        print key, value/float(len(user_input_Nowhitespaces))*100, '%'
        res+='\n'+key+','+`value/float(len(user_input_Nowhitespaces))*100`+'%'

    v.set(res)

root = Tk()
e = Entry(root); assert isinstance(e, object); e.grid(ipadx=5, ipady=5)
button = Button(root, command=let_freq, width=16).grid(ipadx=5, ipady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What if the user inputs a sentence that consists of more than one word?

Comment: In that case we need to tokenize the input string into words. like str="Hello world" `str.strip(" ")` will become "hello", "world". But if input is      "Hello w o r l d" then we get "hello","w","o","r","l","d"

Comment: No, it won't: str="Hello world" str.strip(" ") will NOT become "hello", "world".

Comment: oops typo error. apologizes. its `str.split(" ")`  str.strip will remove spaces at the end or beginning of charcater.

Comment: Alright now. I was going to suggest a documention to read. But okay now, and how are you going to split the parts of a string text and then gather some of them together? Because when you split "Hello world", then as you mentioned above, we get "hello","w","o","r","l","d". And how are you going to gather/assembly them all together, so it will become "world" as a whole and of course it will become a normal sentence again eventually as "Hello world"?

Comment: we cannot gather those chars into world again. I feel no logic would do this. if you know pls suggest me how to achieve that .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122088/discussion-between-vinod-and-parviz-karimli).

Comment: um, well since my question is "BS" I'm wondering if you're aware that it's letter frequency, not word frequency? As I said, every method I found wouldn't work for me, so I feel my question is perfectly valid seeing as I couldn't find a working answer.